# Is there an ItemsControl equivalent for text content?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol, flowdocument

I have some data that I want to present in a `FlowDocument`. This will basically be a view that explains the data in a friendly way, with section headers, paragraphs of text, etc., and which I will display in a FlowDocumentScrollViewer.

To this end, I would like to create a bulleted list (`<List>`) out of the contents of an `ObservableCollection`. I know how to do that with `ItemsControl`, but how do I do it for `ListItem` elements in a `FlowDocument`, since they're part of the `TextElement` class hierarchy rather than the `Control` hierarchy? Is there an equivalent of `ItemsControl` for text content inside a `TextBlock` or `FlowDocument`?

---

**Edit:** The [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx) Sergey linked to is the perfect starting point. The only problem is that the article's code can only use a `Section` or a `TableRowGroup` as the items panel, and doesn't yet support using a `<List>`. But that was trivial to fix -- just a matter of adding this code at the end of `ItemsContent.GenerateContent`, just before the final `else`:

```
else if (panel is List)
    ((List) panel).ListItems.Add((ListItem) element);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking for is possible, but requires significant amount of coding. Fortunately, Vincent Van Den Berghe posted a nice article on the MSDN describing how to [Create Flexible UIs With Flow Documents And Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx) , including the code!

Comment: Awesome. The article won't work with <List> but it only took a small tweak to extend it -- see my edit to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately you can print then the flowdocument directly. You must render it in the flowdocument reader first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `FlowDocument`, you can use an `ItemsControl` and change the panel used to display items to a [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx). This will allow you use the `ItemsControl` as you want, but change its display semantics to a `WrapPanel` (which I believe functions like a `FlowDocument`. You'd do it something like this:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You can set any properties on the inner `WrapPanel` as you desire.

Comment: I see where you're going, but no, that wouldn't use a WrapPanel, it would use a standard StackPanel (since list items are one above the other). Yes, it has crossed my mind to simply abandon FlowDocument and use normal controls, but FlowDocument has its benefits (select+copy, printing), so I'm still curious if there's a way to actually databind inside a FlowDocument.

Comment: I think you missed his point (or i misunderstood your comment), you can replace the StackPanel by setting the ItemsPanelTemplate property, in his example the stackpanel would be replaced by a WrapPanel. You're right though, this doesn't accomplish what you want.

Comment: Sure, I got that. But if I'm generating a bulleted list, I don't *want* to replace the StackPanel with a WrapPanel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the List element:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.list.aspx

Bubblewrap points out a few more details.  You'd likely bind to the ListItems property and need to use a ValueConverter to convert your source list to a list of type ListItemsCollection.

Bubblewrap points out that this is readonly and that the ListItemsCollection has an internal constructor.  So...

I think what you'd have to do is this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding TheArrayOfText, Converter={StaticResource StringsToListConverter}" />
```

This is pretty unfortunate, but I think it would work.  You'd have to write a converter to create a new List object and call `.Add(` on each item.

Comment: But the List element doesnt support binding to an arbitrary collection to generate it's ListItems, does it?

Comment: The ListItems collection should.  You'd have to convert whatever collection it was to a ListItemCollection (via a ValueConverter), but it would give you output in a completely supported and FlowDocumentesque way.

Comment: Except that the ListItems property is readonly and that one is not meant to create a ListItemsCollection themselves. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.listitemcollection.aspx)