# Extending a FlowDocument with custom TextElements in wpf

Tags: wpf

I'd like to extend the functionality of the FlowDocument by creating my own derivatives of Span and Run.

Is this possible and has anyone found any examples?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft did not expose the methods required to render a custom [TextElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.aspx) inside one of their document classes. If you look at the code for a [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.aspx) or [Span](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.span.aspx) there is no actual rendering code. The rendering takes place in [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx)'s built by various internal classes (like FixedTextBuilder).

From MSDN's notes on [FrameworkContentElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkcontentelement.aspx):

> FrameworkContentElement does not yet define its own rendering behavior; instantiating an actual FrameworkContentElement class instance in code or markup is possible but displays nothing in a WPF application user interface (UI). Rendering logic must be provided by classes that take FrameworkContentElement child elements as part of their content model, or in FrameworkContentElement derived classes.

All is not lost, support for rendering custom Block and Inline elements is provided through the [BlockUIContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.blockuicontainer.aspx) and [InlineUIContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inlineuicontainer.aspx) classes. You could then create a low level UIElement which would be hosted inside the fixed or flow document, or use higher level WPF elements.

Comment: I am trying to apply the MVVM-Pattern for a flowdocument. I could accomplish a TextBox with DataBinding but have problems with a BlockUIContainer...

Answer (score 1):

What kind of extensibility is required? Usually when it comes to changing default behavior of any WPF control, that couldn't be changed via inheritance, we use [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615925/repeating-databound-item-in-wpf-flowdocument/1616157#1616157) of `Span` element, that is bound to collection of items. The same trick with attached properties helps with binding `Run` to a text.

The answer will also depend on the `FlowDocument` usage context. If it's in read-only mode, [BlockUIContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.blockuicontainer.aspx) and [InlineUIContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inlineuicontainer.aspx) classes are your friends. But if `FlowDocument` is  inside `RichTextBox`, you'll hate and curse them (problems with copy/paste, undo/redo, etc.) along with whole WPF text support infrastructure.