# How to create context-aware ListBoxItem template?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to create XAML chat interface that will display messages differently depending on it's neighbours. Here's an example:

[image]

I think ListBox control is most suitable for this. I'm also thinking about different controls such as `FlowDocumentReader` but I've never used them. Also I need to mention that message's text should be selectable (across multiple messages) and I don't know how to achieve this with ListBox.

**Update:** The main point there is that if one side (viking in this case) send some messages in a row, the interface should concatenate those (use slim message header instead of full one). So, the look of message with header depends on whether previous message was sent by the same person.

Comment: Not really clear "depending on it's neighbours". What do you mean ? Why do not just relay on modelview/model properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were just interested in the formatting of the Headers (full or small) then a `ListBox`/`ListView`/`ItemsControl` with PreviousData in the `RelativeSource` binding is the way to go (as pointed out by *anivas*).

But since you added that you wanted to support for selection across multiple messages then this pretty much rules out `ItemsControl` and the classes that derives from it as far as I know. You'll have to use something like a [`FlowDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx) instead.

Unfortunately `FlowDocument` doesn't have the `ItemsSource` property. There are examples of workarounds for this, like [Create Flexible UIs With Flow Documents And Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx) but this implementation pretty much makes my VS2010 crash (I didn't investigate the reason for this, might be an easy fix).

**Here is how I would do it**

First you design the Blocks of the `FlowDocument` in the designer and when you're satisfied you move them to a resource where you set `x:Shared="False"`. This will enable you to create multiple instances of the resource instead of using the same one over and over. Then you use an `ObservableCollection` as the "source" for the `FlowDocument` and subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event, and in the eventhandler you get a new instance of the resource, check if you want the full or small header, and then add the blocks to the `FlowDocument`. You could also add logic for Remove etc.

*Example implementation*

```
<!-- xmlns:Collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib" -->

<Window.Resources>
    <Collections:ArrayList x:Key="blocksTemplate" x:Shared="False">
        <!-- Full Header -->
        <Paragraph Name="fullHeader" Margin="5" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" TextAlignment="Right">
            <Figure HorizontalAnchor="ColumnLeft" BaselineAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Margin="0">
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Sender}"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </Figure>
            <Run Text="{Binding TimeSent, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm:ss}}"/>
        </Paragraph>
        <!-- Small Header -->
        <Paragraph Name="smallHeader" Margin="5" TextAlignment="Right">
            <Run Text="{Binding TimeSent, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm:ss}}"/>          
        </Paragraph>
        <!-- Message -->
        <Paragraph Margin="5">
            <Run Text="{Binding Message}"/>
        </Paragraph>
    </Collections:ArrayList>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
        <FlowDocument Name="flowDocument"
                      FontSize="14" FontFamily="Georgia"/>
    </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And the code behind could be along the following lines

```
public ObservableCollection<ChatMessage> ChatMessages
{
    get;
    set;
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ChatMessages = new ObservableCollection<ChatMessage>();
    ChatMessages.CollectionChanged += ChatMessages_CollectionChanged;
}

void ChatMessages_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList itemTemplate = flowDocument.TryFindResource("blocksTemplate") as ArrayList;
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        foreach (ChatMessage chatMessage in e.NewItems)
        {
            foreach (Block block in itemTemplate)
            {
                bool addBlock = true;
                int index = ChatMessages.IndexOf(chatMessage);
                if (block.Name == "fullHeader" &&
                    (index > 0 && ChatMessages[index].Sender == ChatMessages[index - 1].Sender))
                {
                    addBlock = false;
                }
                else if (block.Name == "smallHeader" &&
                         (index == 0 || ChatMessages[index].Sender != ChatMessages[index - 1].Sender))
                {
                    addBlock = false;
                }
                if (addBlock == true)
                {
                    block.DataContext = chatMessage;
                    flowDocument.Blocks.Add(block);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in my sample, `ChatMessage` is just

```
public class ChatMessage
{
    public string Sender
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Message
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DateTime TimeSent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

This will enable you to select text however you like in the messages

[image]

If you're using MVVM you can create an attached behavior instead of the code behind, I made a sample implementation of a similar scenario here: [Binding a list in a FlowDocument to List<MyClass>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615599/binding-a-list-in-a-flowdocument-to-listmyclass)

Also, the MSDN page for `FlowDocument` is very helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx

Comment: don't you need to set x:Shared="False" in order to ensure a new resource instance is created each time?

Comment: @crazyarabian: Yes exactly :) The blocksTemplate resource has x:Shared="False" to ensure that a new instance is created each time. So when the CollectionChanged event is fired, a new ArrayList of blocks is created

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `ItemTemplate` is a `StackPanel` of `TextBlock` header and `TextBlock` message you can use a `MultiBinding` Visibility `Converter` to hide the header as:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}">  
   <TextBlock.Visibility> 
       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource headerVisibilityConverter}"> 
       <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource PreviousData}"/> 
       <Binding/> 
    </MultiBinding>                             
   </TextBlock.Visibility> 
</TextBlock>
```

And the [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) logic goes something like:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    { 
        var previousMessage = values[0] as MessageItem; 
        var currentMessage = values[1] as MessageItem; 
        if ((previousMessage != null) && (currentMessage != null)) 
        { 
            return previousMessage.UserName.Equals(currentMessage.UserName) ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible; 
        }           

        return Visibility.Visible; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a hint *pseudocode like*:

```
public abstract class Message {/*Implementation*/

      public enum MessageTypeEnum {Client, Viking, None};          

      public abstract MessageTypeEnum MessageType {get;}   
}

public class ClientMessage : Message {

      /*Client message concrete implementation.*/
       public override MessageTypeEnum MessageType 
       {
           get { 
               return MessageTypeEnum.Client;
           } 
       }
}

public class VikingMessage : Message 
{     
       / *Viking message concrete implementation*/
       public override MessageTypeEnum MessageType 
       {
           get { 
               return MessageTypeEnum.Viking;
           } 
       }

}
```

After this in yor bindind code in XAML on binding control use XAML attribute `Converter`
Where you can assign a class reference which implements IValueConverter. Here are the links

Resource on web:

[Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx#Y747)

There you can converts the type between your UI/ModelView.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know hos to style single message. I know also how to differently  style messages from different senders. I don't know how to make two adjacent messages from the same sender to use slim header.

Comment: Hmm, probbably I don't get your point, actually. But my post, in short, says: use your data model to define it. Don't relay on XAML to make a miracles, as much easier to do it in ViewModel or Model. I showed ypu how you can defer between different sources, but nothing can stop you from adding new proprerties to the message class to define more accurate relationship/grouping of them and after bind it to UI using Converter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this purely through XAML, you're going to need to have code written somewhere to determine the relationship between each message, i.e., is the the author of message n - 1 the same as n?

I wrote a very quick example that resulted in the desired output. My example and the resulting code snippets are in no way production level code, but it should at least point you in the right direction.

To start, I first created a very simple object to represent the messages:

```
public class ChatMessage
{
  public String Username { get; set; }
  public String Message { get;  set; }
  public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
  public Boolean IsConcatenated { get; set; }
}
```

Next I derived a collection from ObservableCollection to handle determining relationships between each message as they're added:

```
public class ChatMessageCollection : ObservableCollection<ChatMessage>
{
  protected override void InsertItem(int index, ChatMessage item)
  {
    if (index > 0)
      item.IsConcatenated = (this[index - 1].Username == item.Username);

    base.InsertItem(index, item);
  }
}
```

This collection can now be exposed by your ViewModel and bound to the ListBox in your view.

There are many ways to display templated items in XAML. Based on your example interface, the only aspect of each item changing is the header so I figured it made the most sent to have each ListBoxItem display a HeaderedContentControl that would show the correct header based on the IsConcatenated value:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Messages}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:ChatMessage}">
      <HeaderedContentControl Header="{Binding}">
        <HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplateSelector>
          <m:ChatHeaderTemplateSelector />
        </HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplateSelector>

        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Message}" />
      </HeaderedContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You'll notice that I am specifying a HeaderTemplateSelector which is responsible for choosing between one of two header templates:

```
public sealed class ChatHeaderTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    var chatItem = item as ChatMessage;

    if (chatItem.IsConcatenated)
      return ((FrameworkElement)container).FindResource("CompactHeader") as DataTemplate;

    return ((FrameworkElement)container).FindResource("FullHeader") as DataTemplate;
    }
}
```

And finally, here are the two header templates which are defined as resources of the view:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FullHeader">
  <Border
    Background="Lavender"
    BorderBrush="Purple"
    BorderThickness="1"
    CornerRadius="4"
    Padding="2"
    >
    <DockPanel>
      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Username}" />
      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=TimeStamp, StringFormat='{}{0:HH:mm:ss}'}" />
    </DockPanel>
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CompactHeader">
  <Border
    Background="Lavender"
    BorderBrush="Purple"
    BorderThickness="1"
    CornerRadius="4"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    Padding="2"
    >
    <DockPanel>
      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=TimeStamp, StringFormat='{}{0:HH:mm:ss}'}" />
    </DockPanel>
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Again, this example is not perfect and is probably just one of many that works, but at least it should point you in the right direction.