# WPF binding List<string> in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, richtextbox

How binding `List<String>` for RichTextBox. In xaml: Error is `List<string>?`

```
<RichTextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
     Style="{StaticResource RichTextBoxStyle}" Foreground="Red" 
     IsReadOnly="True">
    <FlowDocument>
        <List>
            <ListItem>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Error}"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </ListItem>
        </List>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Seriously error is `List<string>?` ? it's really confusing error :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this

[Repeating databound item in WPF FlowDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615925/repeating-databound-item-in-wpf-flowdocument)

I'm not sure if '*Run*' takes a list. You might have to use a itemscontrol or some other control that takes list items